# What can cause a file corruption of a windows system file (ntdll.dll)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-corruption

I'm observing strange behaviour of a Windows 10 installation and trying to figure out the cause to assess possible damage:

Windows started to act strange in the way that programs which perform system file verifications (like VirtualBox when trying to start a VM) failed with a hint in the log file to `\\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll` and a signature mismatch.
When I right clicked this file and checked the details of the Microsoft Windows signature it indeed said the signature is invalid.

Next I performed a check with the Windows Resource Checker (`sfc \scannow`) and it also found `ntdll.dll` to be corrupted. In its log it looked like several repair tries failed but eventually the file was repaired correctly. This however turned out to be incorrect since I had the same invalid signature and problems after a restart.

Finally I took ownership of `ntdll.dll` (originally it belongs to `TrustedInstaller` and therefore cannot be modified), renamed it to `ntdll.dll.old` and copied a Version from a 3 days old backup in the folder. At this point the hash of copied `ntdll.dll` and `ntdll.dll.old` were different through they had the exact same size and the signature of the copied `ntdll.dll` was valid while the 'old' file still had an invalid signature. 
After a restart everything works like before. However for some really odd reason now the hashs of `ntdll.dll` and `ntdll.dll.old` are matching as well and the signature of `ntdll.dll.old` is valid as well?

Any ideas what kind of problem / cause of the corruption I am facing? SSD SMART values look perfect (the SSD would have been my first culprit). If possible I'd like to prevent more damage and switch maybe defect hardware or take other countermeasures...

Comment: which SSD do you have? Have you updated to last SSD firmware version? AV suite or other filter drivers can cause data corruptions.

Comment: Samsung SSD 840 (I updated the firmware after the whole thing so this all happened with the original firmware) and I only use the built in windows virus protection so I wouldn't guess it will corrupt its own system files but who knows...

Comment: which other software do you use (backup programs)?

Comment: There is an Acronis Backup 12.5 client on this windows installation... and the most recent backup failed ('frozen for 3 days' at 94%). So far I couldn't figure out why it was frozen but if it somehow changed the file it could be the culprit as I terminated it when I renamed the corrupted `ntdll.dll`. Termination failed but the restart helped and that was the same restart from which on `ntdll.dll` and `ntdll.dll.old` again had matching checksums. But maybe it only was another symptom and not the problem, I'll see if I find more logs of acronis...
Thanks for your input so far!